# How to keep tha data saved in textfields when I came back from second viewcontroller?

Tags: swift, uikit, uitextfield, swift5

I am working on a registration form I have to get some data from another view controller when I get back in first viewcontroller my data stored in Text fields were blank. i havent worked with sugues.i have mention important part of code where error could be.

```
class RegisterVC: UIViewController{
@IBAction func emergencyContactTapped(_ sender: Any) {
let vc = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main",  bundle:Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "EmergencyContactVC") as? EmergencyContactVC
           self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)
```

when I get back from conatactsController all my saved data in RegisterVC were gone

```
import UIKit
class EmergencyContactVC: UIViewController{
@IBAction func backTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    let vc = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "RegisterVC") as? RegisterVC
    vc?.phoneText = self.numberArray
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: you have to just add self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true). at not you are doing push controller so each time controller is create new.

Comment: i have to add self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true) this method in second view controller?

Comment: yes you have to add in second view controller.

Answer (score 2):

When you `instantiateViewController` it will create a new object for `RegisterVC`.

Did you try this:

```
@IBAction func backTapped(_ sender: Any) {

    if let navController = self.navigationController {
        navController.popViewController(animated: true)
     }
}
```

Using NSUserDefaults it's easy persistent storage for small information..

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
defaults.setObject(yourString, forKey: "yourKey")
```

Can be retrieved by

```
var retrievedString = defaults.objectForKey("yourKey") as? String
```

Comment: there are more than 10 textfields. using NSuserdefaults would not be complex and difficult? or there any other solution ?

Comment: Yes correct!! Try to just pop not to instantiate again..

Answer (score 0):

@Harish 's answer could be a good solution but, because of userdefaults will store this datas forever (even if you will close the app and open it again), another good solution could be declaring a global variable, so this datas would be stored and used even if you will change viewController and then come back, but they will not be stored if you will close the app.
Declare a variable outside the scope (outside the class) as follow:

```
var abc: String!
class etc... {
     abc = "Your Text"
}
```

This is an exemple so you can use it in another viewcontroller and then use it again when you come back.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, in your example, you have `RegisterVC` pushing `EmergencyContactVC`, and `EmergencyContactVC` pushing `RegisterVC`. You also refer to `contactsController`, but it is unclear how these three are supposed to interact/flow. It seems like `backTapped` should `popViewController`, not instantiate again.

Regardless, there are two appropriate patterns to pass data from VC2 to VC1 when VC1 pushes VC2: delegate and segues.

1. Delegate: This defines a path of communication between VC1 and VC2, allowing VC2 to call methods in VC1 before it disappears. The advantage of protocols over segues is that they can be used at any time during the view controller's lifecycle, between cells and table views, etc. Delegates can be used when passing data amongst several related view controllers.

In VC2, add protocol and properties:

```
protocol VC2Protocol {
    func set( name: String? )
}

class VC2: UIViewController {
    var delegate: VC2Protocol!
    var nameEnteredByUser: String?
    ...
}
```

In VC1, declare the property that you want to receive, and, where you want to push VC2, assign VC1 as the delegate:

```
class VC1: UIViewController {
    var name: String?
    ...
    func pushVC2() {
        if let vc2 = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VC2") as? VC2 {
            vc2.delegate = self
            navigationController?.pushViewController( vc2, animated: true )
        }
    }
}
```

Finally in VC1, you need to implement the protocol:

```
extension VC1: VC2Protocol {
    func set( name: String? ) {
        self.name = name
    }
}
```

Lastly, in VC2, before popping to return to VC1, use the delegate to pass data from VC2 to VC1 while VC2 is still alive:

```
extension VC2 {
    func popVC2() {
        delegate.set( name: nameEnteredByUser )
        navigationController?.popViewController( animated: true )
    }
}
```

2. Segue: When using segues, you can execute code just prior to pushing and popping (or presenting and dismissing), and reference both VC1 and VC2.

There are many detailed tutorials on the web regarding using segues. For passing data back, the trick is to create an unwind segue to be invoked when popping VC2 to VC1. In VC1, you would have something like:

```
func unwindToVC1( _ segue: UIStoryboardSegue ) {
    if let vc2 = segue.source as? VC2 {
        self.name = vc2.nameEnteredByUserInVC2
    }
}
```

You can also pass data from VC1 to VC2 using `override func prepare( for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any? )` in VC1.